# ClickOnce deployment to web server - available online only

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, webserver, clickonce, vb.net-2010

```
PLATFORM VERSION INFO
Windows                  : 6.1.7601.65536 (Win32NT)
Common Language Runtime  : 4.0.30319.296
System.Deployment.dll    : 4.0.30319.1 (RTMRel.030319-0100)
clr.dll                  : 4.0.30319.296 (RTMGDR.030319-2900)
dfdll.dll                : 4.0.30319.1 (RTMRel.030319-0100)
dfshim.dll               : 4.0.31106.0 (Main.031106-0000)

SOURCES
Deployment url           : http://apps4you.comyr.com/appTest8   /snake.application
Server                   : Apache

IDENTITIES
Deployment Identity      : snake.application, Version=1.0.0.6,  Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=5bd57d3abffa2377, processorArchitecture=x86

APPLICATION SUMMARY
* Online only application.
* Trust url parameter is set.

ERROR SUMMARY
Below is a summary of the errors, details of these errors are listed later in the log.
* Activation of http://apps4you.comyr.com/appTest8/snake.application resulted in exception. Following failure messages were detected:
    + Exception reading manifest from http://apps4you.comyr.com/appTest8 /Application%20Files/snake_1_0_0_6/snake.exe.manifest: the manifest may not be valid or  the file could not be opened.
    + Unexpected end of file has occurred. The following elements are not  closed: br, br. Line 3, position 254.

COMPONENT STORE TRANSACTION FAILURE SUMMARY
No transaction error was detected.

WARNINGS
There were no warnings during this operation.

OPERATION PROGRESS STATUS
* [15/04/2013 5:23:29 p.m.] : Activation of http://apps4you.comyr.com/appTest8/snake.application has started.
* [15/04/2013 5:23:31 p.m.] : Processing of deployment manifest has successfully completed.
* [15/04/2013 5:23:31 p.m.] : Installation of the application has started.

ERROR DETAILS
Following errors were detected during this operation.
* [15/04/2013 5:23:31 p.m.] System.Deployment.Application.InvalidDeploymentException (ManifestParse)
    - Exception reading manifest from http://apps4you.comyr.com/appTest8/Application%20Files/snake_1_0_0_6/snake.exe.manifest: the manifest may not be valid or the file could not be opened.
    - Source: System.Deployment
    - Stack trace:
        at    System.Deployment.Application.ManifestReader.FromDocument(String localPath, ManifestType manifestType, Uri sourceUri)
        at System.Deployment.Application.DownloadManager.DownloadApplicationManifest(AssemblyManifest deploymentManifest, String targetDir, Uri deploymentUri, IDownloadNotification notification, DownloadOptions options, Uri& appSourceUri, String& appManifestPath)
        at System.Deployment.Application.DownloadManager.DownloadApplicationManifest(AssemblyManifest deploymentManifest, String targetDir, Uri deploymentUri, Uri& appSourceUri, String& appManifestPath)
        at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.DownloadApplication(SubscriptionState subState, ActivationDescription actDesc, Int64 transactionId, TempDirectory& downloadTemp)
        at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.InstallApplication(SubscriptionState& subState, ActivationDescription actDesc)
        at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.PerformDeploymentActivation(Uri activationUri, Boolean isShortcut, String textualSubId, String deploymentProviderUrlFromExtension, BrowserSettings browserSettings, String& errorPageUrl)
        at  System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.ActivateDeploymentWorker(Object state)
    --- Inner Exception ---
    System.Xml.XmlException
    - Unexpected end of file has occurred. The following elements are not closed: br, br. Line 3, position 254.
    - Source: System.Xml
    - Stack trace:
        at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Throw(String res, String arg)
        at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseElementContent()
        at System.Deployment.Application.ManifestValidatingReader.XmlFilteredReader.Read()
        at System.Deployment.Application.ManifestValidatingReader.XmlFilteredReader.Read()
        at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Skip()
        at System.Deployment.Application.ManifestValidatingReader.XmlFilteredReader.Read()
        at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Skip()
        at System.Deployment.Application.ManifestValidatingReader.XmlFilteredReader.Read()
        at System.Xml.XmlCharCheckingReader.Read()
        at System.Xml.XsdValidatingReader.Read()
        at   System.Deployment.Application.ManifestReader.FromDocument(String localPath, ManifestType manifestType, Uri sourceUri)

COMPONENT STORE TRANSACTION DETAILS
No transaction information is available.
```

Comment: There should be a 'Details...' button on the error dialog. Click that and see if there is anything meaningful in the actual error message.

Comment: Cheers - there are some details. Looks to me like its having issues downloading the application manifest.

Answer (score 0):

Your deployment [URL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_resource_locator) **is wrong**.

According to:

> Activation of C:\Users\user\Downloads\snake.application resulted in
>   exception. Following failure messages were detected:
>       + Deployment and application do not have matching security zones.

the URL

```
file:///C:/Users/user/Downloads/snake.application
```

should be

```
http://apps4you.comyr.com/appTest7/
```

so the browser knows via the manifest that the application is deployed on the same location as the publisher intended and is not tampered. It is a security issue.

In the [publish tab](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c37e68bc%28v=vs.80%29.aspx):

```
In the Installation URL field, enter the installation
location using a fully qualified URL using the format  http://www.microsoft.com/ApplicationName, or a
UNC path using the format \\Server\ApplicationName.
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your comment- this was due to using Mozilla. The second lot of details is what I am receiving now.

Comment: I believe clickonce doesn't work in Mozilla. You need a pulgin for that: https://addons.mozilla.org/nl/firefox/addon/microsoft-net-framework-assist/

Comment: Yep Cheers - onto this now. The problem is now with the manifest. Any chance you know how to fix?

Answer (score -3):

Check *[Bring back the basic setup and deployment project type Visual Studio Installer](http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/3041773-bring-back-the-basic-setup-and-deployment-project-)*.

Comment: This is/was definitely an issue but ClickOnce applications are not exactly tied to InstallShield or MSI projects. The publication properties determine the setup executable's actions upon launch, and are generally updated every time it is launched when an update is available. The question was directly in correlation with an online deployment where a user can download the application and get updates automatically via a web server deployment.